# How do I run a set of Python NLP algorithms and export the results to an Angular application?

Tags: python, angular, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have the following at hand to work with:

- a front-end Angular mobile-optimised application that displays the sentiments of a set of comments on a user-specified YouTube video, with the sentiments being calculated from various sentiment analysis packages.
- a publicly available set of Python sentiment analysis tools (available [here](https://github.com/AbCd256/Quality-of-sentiment-analysis-tools)) which will be used to process the sentiments.

My question is since the app uses Angular (TypeScript) and the sentiment analysis packages use Python, what is the best way that I can build a connection from the user input (YouTube URL) to the Python packages? Should I use Django, Flask or another backend library, or will that not be required? The Angular application is already fully functional with JavaScript-based sentiment analysis tools; now I have to integrate the Python-based tools into it.

Comment: Your question seems to not meet the [on-topic criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. Your question is largely not precise enough to give us matter to answer in a non-opiniated way : what are your technical requirements ? Are you proficient with client/server programming ? Do you have experience in any solution ? ...

Comment: I believe I have specified the technical requirements of the problem clearly: given a YouTube comment, an Angular application shows its computed sentiment. Previously the sentiment was computed through inbuilt JavaScript packages. Now I have to use other packages written in Python, and I need to know a way to send the YouTube URL from the Angular front-end to the Python computation, and display the resulting sentiments from multiple packages in the front-end UI. Hope I am clear enough. For the record, I have some expertise in client/server programming, and I want to know what solution is best.

Comment: You specified what you want to do, but your questions does not ask for **how**, but **what is best**. "best" is a word that means nothing without context, context which I tried to obtain with the questions in my first comment. There is no **absolute best** answer, only contextual ones. Your requirements regarding the backend are basically "it can receive a request, call some Python, then sent a response back. That's the definition of a web server, not technical requirements. If you want an answer anyway, go Django, it's the most popular.

Comment: That final answer is all I needed. Thank you!